# How to make a portable javafx application?

Tags: javafx, desktop-application

I want to make a portable javafx application with JRE inside for Windows systems. I can make a jar and I aware about javapackage tool, but I can't find a simple way to create a portable application and wrap it in exe.

Comment: What are you asking?  What is your definition of a portable application ?  In what way does [self-contained application packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html) and the documentation on it provided by Oracle not fit your requirements or needs?

Comment: I want to make bundle with my .jar, .jre and .exe and possibility to running it on any computer with windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Inno Setup for it, it's really simple. And even integrated if you are under Eclipse

I found all the informations about how to use it here
http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/

Basically, you download it from http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php and install it. Then you just need to set its path in your environment variables so that eclipse knows how to run it